# Python/Pycharm: For loop fetching string instead of Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I am new to python so this may seem like a very stupid question, please bear with me.

I am using the following code: 
(image if debug also attached)

```
for connector in la_details['properties']['parameters']['$connections']['value']:
    if connector['connectionName'] in allowed_connectors:
        result = True
```

[image: Pycharm Debug]

Now, instead of fetching a 'dict' value in 'connector' variable, it fetches a 'string', due to which the 'if' statement gives the error:

```
string indices must be integers
```

Can someone please guide me how to get 'dict' values instead of 'string'? I tried to google but couldn't find anything that matches this scenario, maybe because I am using the wrong terminology.

EDIT: print(la_details) produces the following output:

```
{u'name': u'REDACTED',
 u'tags': {},
 u'id': u'/subscriptions/REDACTED/resourceGroups/REDACTED/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/REDACTED',
 u'location': u'REDACTED',
 u'type': u'Microsoft.Logic/workflows',
 u'properties': {u'definition': {u'parameters': {u'$connections': {u'defaultValue': {}, u'type': u'Object'}}, u'triggers': {u'Recurrence': {u'recurrence': {u'frequency': u'Month', u'interval': 1}, u'type': u'Recurrence'}}, u'outputs': {}, u'actions': {u'Send_an_email_(V2)': {u'inputs': {u'body': {u'Body': u'<p>TEST</p>', u'To': u'REDACTED', u'Subject': u'TEST'}, u'path': u'/v2/Mail', u'host': {u'connection': {u'name': u"@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"}}, u'method': u'post'}, u'runAfter': {}, u'type': u'ApiConnection'}, u'Get_tables_(V2)': {u'inputs': {u'path': u"/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/tables", u'host': {u'connection': {u'name': u"@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"}}, u'method': u'get'}, u'runAfter': {u'Send_an_email_(V2)': [u'Succeeded']}, u'type': u'ApiConnection'}}, u'contentVersion': u'1.0.0.0', u'$schema': u'https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#'}, u'version': u'REDACTED', u'parameters': {u'$connections': {u'value': {u'office365': {u'connectionId': u'/subscriptions/REDACTED/resourceGroups/REDACTED/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365', u'id': u'/subscriptions/REDACTED/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365', u'connectionName': u'office365'}, u'sql': {u'connectionId': u'/subscriptions/REDACTED/resourceGroups/REDACTED/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql', u'id': u'/subscriptions/REDACTED/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/sql', u'connectionName': u'sql'}}}}, u'integrationServiceEnvironment': {u'type': u'Microsoft.Logic/integrationServiceEnvironments', u'name': u'ise-demo-res', u'id': u'/subscriptions/REDACTED/resourceGroups/REDACTED/providers/Microsoft.Logic/integrationServiceEnvironments/ise-demo-res'}, u'endpointsConfiguration': {u'connector': {u'outgoingIpAddresses': [{u'address': u'40.71.11.80/28'}, {u'address': u'REDACTED'}, {u'address': u'REDACTED'}, {u'address': u'REDACTED'}, {u'address': u'REDACTED'}, {u'address': u'REDACTED'}, {u'address': u'REDACTED'}, {u'address': u'REDACTED'}, {u'address': u'REDACTED'}]}, u'workflow': {u'outgoingIpAddresses': [{u'address': u'REDACTED'}, {u'address': u'REDACTED'}], u'accessEndpointIpAddresses': [{u'address': u'REDACTED'}]}}, u'state': u'Enabled', u'accessEndpoint': u'REDACTED', u'createdTime': u'2020-03-12T14:45:34.6908438Z', u'changedTime': u'2020-04-08T10:35:32.3388762Z', u'provisioningState': u'Succeeded'}}
```

Comment: Can you add a print of la_details in your question please

Comment: Added the print of la_details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python `for ... in ...` returns either the value in the case of lists or the key in the case for dictionaries (as in your example), below is the correct way to do your loop.

```
la_details = {
  'properties': {
    'parameters': {
      '$connections': {
        'value': {
          'office365': { 'connectionName': 'office365' },
          'sql': { 'connectionName': 'sql' },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

allowed_connectors = ['sql']

#for connector in la_details['properties']['parameters']['$connections']['value']:
#  if connector['connectionName'] in allowed_connectors:
#    return True
#  else:
#    return 'False

values = la_details['properties']['parameters']['$connections']['value']

for connector in values:
  if values[connector]['connectionName'] in allowed_connectors:
    print('{0} is allowed'.format(values[connector]['connectionName']))
  else:
    print('{0} is not allowed'.format(values[connector]['connectionName']))
```

Comment: "the name of the property in the case for dictionaries" => it's named a "key" - properties are [something totally different](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties)

Comment: Also you might be interested in the `dict.items()` method.

Comment: Oh and yes, you probably meant "lists" instead of "arrays" ;-)

Comment: My mistake, I don't do much python lol my go to is JavaScript/C#. Please feel free to edit my answer and improve it